# why navsat_transform_node needs imu?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, navsat-transform-node, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to the field, so this question might be obvious, but I wonder, why IMU is needed once I have GPS absolute position and odometry from robot?

If I have GPS coordinates and odometry, shouldn't be possible to create UTM coordinates?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353887/why-navsat_transform_node-needs-imu?/) by [dpetrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/40203/dpetrini/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @dpetrini,

As far as I know (if this is not correct, please someone point it out), the `navsat_transform_node` needs an IMU topic since with the GPS you are not able to provide a proper estimation of your orientation. If you take a look in `rviz` at the odometry provided by a GPS, if you are static, the orientation is just plotted with a directed arrow with random orientation, this is due to the fact that the orientation is calculated taking into account the current GPS position and a random close position. With the IMU you can provide a high precisse orientation information, allowing the localization process to be more accurate.

However, since the `nav_msgs/Odometry` input messages come usually from `EFK` or `UKF` nodes, you can activate the `use_odometry_yaw` flag to avoid using an IMU topic as input for the `navsat_transform_node`. Nonetheless, you will have to take into account that this last fussion needs to contain a proper orientation information. As I see, either your odometry contains a good orientation somehow, or you are forced to use the IMU data, either in the fussion process of `UKF`/`EFK` or directly as input in the `navsat_transform_node`.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dpetrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/40203/dpetrini/) on 2020-06-15**:
hi @Weasfas, thanks for the answer, it clarifies the orientation issues. However my point was more high level in terms of the need to have IMU at all if I have GPS which is absolute. The point I found in other answer is that with GPS I could get orientation by integrating positions and thus knowing speed and direction. One comment here [link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/215904/robot_localization-failed-to-transform-warning/?answer=216182#post-id-216182)  tells about that.
For my doubt I consider is ok with your answer and this comment. But I realize that if I manage to integrate GPS, the period is very low (1 Hz) so probably quality will be not good so I guess I will have to improve IMU magnetometer readings (MPU9250) by proper calibrating it.